# protractor executes the script but timesout

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I'm using protractor with cucumber. My script executes till the end and once done keeps waiting and timesout. On returning promise it skips the execution and abruplty ends

```
enter code here

Then('*************************** , function(callback){
browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;
browser.switchTo().defaultContent().then(function(){
    return navigator.sendKeys("abc", protractor.Key.ENTER);

}.then(function(){
    return browser.switchTo().frame(0);
});
column.getText().then(function(text){
    return expect(text).contain("expectedString");
});
callback();
});
```

I m not sure what i m missing here. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**  return a promise, instead of using `callback`

```
Then('*************************** , function(){
  browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;
  browser.switchTo().defaultContent().then(function(){
      return navigator.sendKeys("abc", protractor.Key.ENTER);

  }.then(function(){
      return browser.switchTo().frame(0);
  });

  // return a promise as function return value
  return column.getText().then(function(text){
      return expect(text).contain("expectedString");
  });
});
```

**Option 2** invoke the `callbak()` in `promise.then()`

```
Then('*************************** , function(callback){
  browser.ignoreSynchronization= true;
  browser.switchTo().defaultContent().then(function(){
      return navigator.sendKeys("abc", protractor.Key.ENTER);

  }.then(function(){
      return browser.switchTo().frame(0);
  });
  column.getText().then(function(text){
      expect(text).contain("expectedString");
      return callback();
  });
});
```